# Remove indent from proof in IEEEtran

Tags: amsmath, indentation, ieeetran

I use `proof` of `amsmath` package. With `IEEEtran` by default there is an indent before proof. Is there a way to remove it?

Comment: Please add a minimal example of code showing the issue.

Answer (score 3):

First, I agree with @vonbrand on the advice to adhere to the specific journal rules and not to change settings by yourself; its their responsibility not yours and they will end up editing the whole paper again prior to publication.

But, if you have to, you can use the `etoolbox` package to patch the relevant command in the `.cls` file to force it behave the way you want. The relevant line in the class file is this:

```
\def\IEEEproofindentspace{2\parindent}
```

and you use it by adding in the preamble the following:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%\def\IEEEproofindentspace{2\parindent} % This is the line to be patched
\patchcmd{\IEEEproofindentspace}{2\parindent}{0pt}{}{}
```

Of course, you can also use a shorter form without the need for the `etoolbox` package by redefining the command like this `\renewcommand{\IEEEprofindentspace}{0pt}`, as suggested by egreg in a comment.

Comment: Just `\renewcommand{\IEEEproofindentspace}{0pt}` should suffice

Comment: @egreg  Yes, I just wanted to emphasize the standard definition `\patchcmd{<command>}{<code to replace>}{<code>}{<success>}{<failure>}`.

Comment: The fact is that you ***don't*** need `\patchcmd`. Why using a gun for a mosquito?

Comment: Yes, got your point the last second and edited accordingly, thank you.

Comment: @AboAmmar thanks, but this does not work, it does not change the indent. Just in case, I use IEEEtran 1.7b.

Comment: @BenBost -- A MWE would save your day and help people here detect your specific problem, but, you didn't provide one. `IEEEtran` has too many settings according to the journal or conference you are submitting to.

Answer (score 0):

If there are spaces  (or other characteristics you don't like) in your chosen journal's format, they probably want it that way; and if they don't like it either, they'll will want to keep it, even if only for consistency's sake.

Comment: This reads more like a comment than as a standalone answer.