# How can you remove the parindent in IEEEtran?

Tags: indentation, ieeetran, parindent

I am currently writing a paper using the IEEEtran package. I already read the IEEEtran How to? and studied the demo files but I just could not find a way to remove the parindent. I know this is against
the original intention of the package but is there a way how I could remove them?

I found this similar question that shows how to remove the indent from the proof:

[Remove indent from proof in IEEEtran](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279863/remove-indent-from-proof-in-ieeetran)

Could I use something similiar like \renewcommand{\IEEEproofindentspace}{0pt} ?

Here is my MVP-IEEEtran template:

```
\documentclass[
    10pt,                                   
    final,                                      
    journal,                                    
    compsoc,                                
    a4paper,                                
    twoside,                                
    twocolumn                                   
]{IEEEtran}


\begin{document}

    \title{Personal IEEEtran MVP}

    \author{Author}

    \markboth{\LaTeX\ Paper}{Title}

    \IEEEtitleabstractindextext{

        \begin{abstract}
            Lorem Ipsum Abstract
        \end{abstract}

        \begin{IEEEkeywords}
            Computer Society, IEEE, IEEEtran, journal, \LaTeX, paper, template.
        \end{IEEEkeywords}

    }

    \maketitle

    \IEEEraisesectionheading{\section{Einleitung}\label{sec:introduction}}

    \IEEEPARstart{T}{his} demo file is intended to serve as a ``starter file''
    for IEEE Computer Society journal papers produced under \LaTeX\ using
    IEEEtran.cls version 1.8b and later. I wish you the best of success.

    \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt 
    ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo 

    dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit 
    amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor 
    invidunt 

    ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo 
    dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit 
    amet.

\end{document}
```

It looks like this:
[image]

I do not want to have the yellow marked indents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set `\parindent` to `0pt` like you would in any normal document:

[image]

```
\documentclass[
  10pt,
  final,
  journal,
  compsoc,
  a4paper,
  twoside,
  twocolumn
]{IEEEtran}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Remove paragraph indentation

\begin{document}

\title{Personal IEEEtran MVP}

\author{Author}

\markboth{\LaTeX\ Paper}{Title}

\IEEEtitleabstractindextext{

  \begin{abstract}
    Lorem Ipsum Abstract
  \end{abstract}

  \begin{IEEEkeywords}
    Computer Society, IEEE, IEEEtran, journal, \LaTeX, paper, template.
  \end{IEEEkeywords}

}

\maketitle

\IEEEraisesectionheading{\section{Einleitung}\label{sec:introduction}}

\IEEEPARstart{T}{his} demo file is intended to serve as a ``starter file''
for IEEE Computer Society journal papers produced under \LaTeX\ using
IEEEtran.cls version 1.8b and later. I wish you the best of success.

\subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt 
ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo 

dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit 
amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor 
invidunt 

ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo 
dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit 
amet.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :).This worked perfectly